# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CartController::destroy(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

Am using darryldecode ShoppingCart library but I keep getting the above error when am trying to remove an item from my cart, I don't know what am missing. Here is my code below.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Cart::remove($id);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

This is my route.

```
Route::delete('/cart', 'CartController@destroy')->name('cart.destroy');
```

And here is my view

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.destroy') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link mr-2" style="color: gray">Remove</button>
</form>
```

What am I missing? Thanks for your concern!

Comment: you need to pass id ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Route:**

```
Route::delete('/cart/{id}', 'CartController@destroy')->name('cart.destroy');
```

**Form:** you need to pass in the `cart-id` in your form

```
<form action="{{ route('cart.destroy', ['id' => $id]) }}" method="POST">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Delete" />
    @method('delete')
    @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: this what it shows when I change to that     "Missing required parameters for [Route: cart.destroy] [URI: cart{id}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\E-Commerce\resources\views\pages\cart.blade.php)"

Comment: I would recommend using `route('cart.destroy', ['id' => $id])` instead of `url()` though. That's what named routes are there for.

Comment: This is what I have by using the route and url "Undefined variable: id (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\E-Commerce\resources\views\pages\cart.blade.php) "

Comment: You need to specify `cart-id` over there, check in which variable you are passing in the cart-id.